# Why FragmentManager doesn't remove fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using this code to add a `Fragment` to my layout:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.frameLayout, newFragment, newFragment.getClass().getName())
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
    .commit();
```

Where `newFragment` is a new `Fragment` which I want to show.

The next code I'm using to remove the fragment from `FragmentManager`:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(newFragment.getClass().getName());

if(fragment != null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .remove(fragment)
        .commit();
}
```

But it didn't work! If I want to the get same fragment from `FragmentManager` with `findFragmentByTag` it returns it.

My question is how can I remove my `Fragment` from `FragmentManager` ?

Comment: Do you get a error message? Or does your fragment simply remain on your screen? Is the `remove` executed?

Comment: @Amy no any errors.
`remove` executed, but i still can get this fragment with `findFragmentByTag`

Comment: The `Fragment` remains in the `FragmentManager` if `removed`, it is not destroyed.

Comment: Sorry, just a quick one: it is okay, if you using replace and you want to remove that fragment too ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure u r using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`
   and `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;`

   - if the import are incorrect then no error but NULL fragment is returned while removing so its not removed.
2. I have added FirstFragment on Frame inside MainActivity same as your way.

   ```
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.myFrame, firstFrag, firstFrag.getClass().getName())
           .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
           .commit();
   ```
3. and on Backpress I'm removing that Fragment using ur code as below -

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed(){

       Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                         .findFragmentByTag(firstFrag.getClass().getName());

       if(fragment != null) {
           getSupportFragmentManager()
               .beginTransaction()
               .remove(fragment)
               .commit();
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: @Yuriy Kolbasinskiy: check my answer :) Hope it helps.

Comment: @miho39: wts the problem?

Comment: I created new issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56095728/fragment-still-exist-after-remove-in-sdk-24