# Fragment still exist after remove in SDK < 24

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm facing the problem about removing Fragment in SDK < 24.

removeFragment()

```
FragmentTransaction frgTrans = fragmentMng.beginTransaction();
MyFragment myFrg = (MyFragment) fragmentMng.findFragmentByTag(TAG_MY_FRAGMENT);
frgTrans.remove(myFrg).commit();
```

getFragment()

```
MyFragment myFrg = (MyFragment) fragmentMng.findFragmentByTag(TAG_MY_FRAGMENT);
if (myFrg == null ) {
   // Do sth
}
// But I checked that myFrg is NOT NULL ???
```

Furthermore, this problem only happened in SDK < 24 ( Android 5,6 ).
What's difference things between Android SDK < 24 and 24 above ?
I also try to call `commitNow()` for execute synchronously but it's same problem.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    frgTrans.commit();
    fragmentMng.popBackStack();
} else {
    frgTrans.commitNow();
}
```

Anyone here has same problem ?

**Update:**
I also check Fragment `hashcode` I get before add and before remove. It's same so I can affirm that it's existing...

```
05-12 11:34:38.705 3916-3916/myapp.test E/FragmentControllerTest: hashcode before remove: 136290746  
05-12 11:34:39.856 3916-3916/myapp.test E/FragmentControllerTest: hashcode before add: 136290746
```

**Update code**
Calling follow:

```
GotoActivity 1: AddMyFragment()  
GotoActivity 2: (destroy Activity1 ) removeMyFragment()  
BackToActivity1: AddMyFragment() (onResume)
```

Code:

```
private void addMyFragment() {
    MyFragment myFrg = (MyFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_MY_FRAGMENT);
    if (myFrg == null) {
        try {
            myFrg = new MyFragment();
            FragmentTransaction frgTrans = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            frgTrans.add(R.id.my_fragment, myFrg, TAG_MY_FRAGMENT);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                frgTrans.commit();
            } else {
                frgTrans.commitNow();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "hash code after remove: " + myFrg.hashCode());
    }
}  

private void removeMyFragment() {   
    MyFragment myFrg = (MyFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_MY_FRAGMENT);
    if (myFrg != null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "hash code after add: " + myFrg.hashCode());
        try {
            FragmentTransaction frgTrans = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            frgTrans.remove(myFrg);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                frgTrans.commit();
                mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            } else {
                frgTrans.commitNow();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using `remove(searchFragment)`, not `remove(myFrg)`. Is that intentional or why would `myFrg` be removed after you remove some other Fragment? Are you using `android.app.Fragment`?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo. I already edited my question.  
I'm using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: There's no API level checks in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, so there's no differences between API levels. If you use `commitNow()` and immediately check with `findFragmentByTag()`, what result do you get? Have you added multiple Fragments with the same tag (i.e., if you use `toString()`, are they actually the same Fragment)?

Comment: If I use `commitNow()` after remove. I still can get fragment when I find by Tag. 
Also, before add Fragment I get fragment by Tag then check if it Null or Not null. If it is null, I will add . Else do nothing. 
So multiple same Fragment will not be added !

Comment: Please show your code of doing a `commitNow()` removal and then finding the same Fragment.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I added the code at description. Can you have a look. Thank you !

Comment: `commit()` is asynchronous - calling `findFragmentByTag()` immediately after won't reflect what is removed - that's why `commitNow()` exists (to update the state immediately). There's absolutely never any reason to do anything different based on API level, so please don't do that. If you want it to be immediate, use `commitNow()` on all API levels. You still aren't showing that immediately after a `commitNow()` on your `remove()` that the Fragment isn't properly removed.

Comment: I've already tried to use `commitNow` on all API levels. But fragment still existing.