# Remove Fragment from Activity when user calls for another Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I need the best way to implement my use case as below:
There are 2 activities : MainActivity and ListActivity

- Use case :
  When MainActivity is called, there is 1 Fragment ( BottomFragment) that is `removed/added` into Activity in `onResume()`. Then I click the button in BottomFragment, ListActivity will be called by `startActivityForResult()`.

  And if choose item in List -> back to MainActivity by `setResult(RESULT_OK)` and `finish()`.
  Now when `onResume()`method of MainActivity invokes, `removed/added` is called again.
- Problem:
  I do NOT think this is the best way to implement my use case. Because I'm facing a problem that Fragment can NOT be removed in device SDK < 24.

Does anyone have any idea? Thank you

Comment: @user1241241 
I updated code here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56095728/fragment-still-exist-after-remove-in-sdk-24?noredirect=1#comment98827989_56095728

Comment: there is a minor bug in your code. Fixing this minor bug in your code will be giving you the expected result.

Comment: Where is the bug ? If you can not show me I dont need the answer like this.

Comment: Why are you adding the fragment in onResume why not in onCreate of the activity's lifecycle?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

You can read this article for understanding android lifecycle. When you called the second activity, your MainActivity calls `onStop()`. When you return back to the MainActivity, `onRestart()` ,`onStart()` and `onResume()` will be called. You can add your **BottomFragment** in `onCreate()`. This will fix your issue.